# How to install Eclipse Paho Client View

Tags: java, eclipse, mqtt, paho

I am completely new to Eclipse Paho and I am trying to undertstand the basics and get a test environment up and running.

I have tracked down the org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.2.jar. I created a test Eclipse project and successfully connected with the sample code provided [here](http://eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/).

Now, I would like to learn how to install the Eclipse Paho Client View. 
I have searched online but wasn't able to find any definite answers.
I would like to have the Eclipse Paho Client View available in my Eclipse (Luna).

[image]

Thank you in advance for any tips and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to export the project as an eclipse plugin that you can then install into your eclipse instance.

The following should have instructions to help:

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fui_export_install_into_host.htm

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am just trying to get an existing plugin running in Eclipse. I found the plugin source code online with instructions how to install here: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/tree/master/org.eclipse.paho.client.eclipse.view. But I am unable to install it. There is no site.xml in the jar file. Any tips to get this plugin running in Eclipse? Thanks!

Comment: If you get the right export options for the project it should create you a site.xml